# ros-by-example vol2. catkin_make rbx2 error

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing the  ros-by-example vol2 code2, and have a build problem with rbx2.

**Below is command line:**

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src

git clone https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1.git

cd rbx1

git checkout indigo-devel

cd ~/catkin_ws

catkin_make
```

---

**Below is the error message:**

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "shape_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    shape_msgsConfig.cmake
    shape_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "shape_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "shape_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "shape_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      rbx2/rbx2_arm_nav/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'shape_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "shape_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    shape_msgsConfig.cmake
    shape_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "shape_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "shape_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "shape_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  rbx2/rbx2_arm_nav/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247135/ros-by-example-vol2.-catkin_make-rbx2-error/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the preformatted text button, the next time (the one with 1s and 0s for code).

You are missing a dependency, namely `shape_msgs`

Install with `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-shape-msgs` and recompile

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
Thanks, it helps